Error regarding my Python ANTLR parser code
I am trying to parse the contents of my test case files to output files to where the token type and the production rules are displayed.
My test case is this:
[* operator test *] = != > < <= => + - * / == +-*/w  [* separator test *] $ { } ; , () = )(  [* keyword *] integer  boolean   real  {} ; ,  if else endif return scan while endwhile  true false   [* integer *] 1 1000 99 00000000000000  [* real *] 234.567 9.000001 000.00  [* identifier *] z12_d_ Zzzz a1z4r zbc12__x  x  [* wrongTokens *]   #   _   23rty   000.   .123

Now i am getting this error and only this error and i cannot figure out why
line 2:0 mismatched input '=' expecting {'function', 'if', 'while', 'return', 'scan', 'print', 'integer', 'boolean', 'real', '{', IDENTIFIER}
My g4 file for my rules/grammar is down below and i just want my parser to recognize '=' as an output.

grammar RAT24S;

program             : (functionDefinition | declaration | statement)+ EOF;

functionDefinition  : FUNCTION identifier '(' parameterList? ')' LBRACE body RBRACE;
parameterList       : parameter (COMMA parameter)*;
parameter           : qualifier identifier;
body                : (declaration | statement)*;
declaration         : qualifier identifier (COMMA identifier)* SEMICOLON;
statement           : assignStatement
                    | ifStatement
                    | whileStatement
                    | returnStatement
                    | printStatement
                    | scanStatement
                    | compoundStatement;

assignStatement     : identifier ASSIGN expression SEMICOLON ;
ifStatement         : IF LPAREN expression RPAREN statement (ELSE statement)?;
whileStatement      : WHILE LPAREN expression RPAREN statement;
returnStatement     : RETURN expression? SEMICOLON;
printStatement      : PRINT LPAREN expression RPAREN SEMICOLON;
scanStatement       : SCAN LPAREN identifier RPAREN SEMICOLON;
compoundStatement   : LBRACE statement* RBRACE;

expression          : term (add_op term)*;
term                : factor (mul_op factor)*;
factor              : identifier
                    | INTEGER_LITERAL
                    | REAL_LITERAL
                    | LPAREN expression RPAREN;

identifier          : IDENTIFIER;

qualifier           : INTEGER
                    | BOOLEAN
                    | REAL;

// Tokens
FUNCTION            : 'function';
IF                  : 'if';
ELSE                : 'else';
WHILE               : 'while';
RETURN              : 'return';
SCAN                : 'scan';
PRINT               : 'print';
TRUE                : 'true';
FALSE               : 'false';
INTEGER             : 'integer';
BOOLEAN             : 'boolean';
REAL                : 'real';
VOID                : 'void';
PUBLIC              : 'public';
PRIVATE             : 'private';
ENDWHILE            : 'endwhile';

ASSIGN              : '=';
ADD                 : '+';
SUB                 : '-';
MUL                 : '*';
DIV                 : '/';
EQ                  : '==';
NE                  : '!=';
LT                  : '<';
LE                  : '<=';
GT                  : '>';
GE                  : '>=';
INC                 : '++';
DEC                 : '--';

LPAREN              : '(';
RPAREN              : ')';
LBRACE              : '{';
RBRACE              : '}';
SEMICOLON           : ';';
COMMA               : ',';
WS                  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
COMMENT             : '[*' .*? '*]' -> skip; // skip comments enclosed in [* *]

IDENTIFIER          : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
INTEGER_LITERAL     : [0-9]+;
REAL_LITERAL        : [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]+;

// Define explicit tokens for characters to avoid implicit token creation
SEPARATOR           : '$';
IGNORED_CHAR        : [#._]; // Ignore these characters

// Operator tokens
add_op              : ADD | SUB;
mul_op              : MUL | DIV;




What input is causing this error/warning? Input like Q=42; is properly parsed as an assignStatement.

My test case file
= != > < <= => + - * / ==
+-*/w

[* separator test *]
$ { } ; , () =
)(

[* keyword *]
integer  boolean   real  {} ; ,  if else endif return scan while endwhile
 true false


[* integer *]
1 1000 99 00000000000000

[* real *]
234.567 9.000001 000.00

[* identifier *]
z12_d_ Zzzz a1z4r zbc12__x  x

[* wrongTokens *]
  #
  _
  23rty
  000.
  .123````


It is supposed to recognize anything as an integer, real number, identifier, operator, separator, or keyword, or skip if none of the above.

There is nothing wrong with your lexer rules. The lexer successfully creates the following 63 tokens given your example input:
63 tokens:
  1    ASSIGN                         '='
  2    NE                             '!='
  3    GT                             '>'
  4    LT                             '<'
  5    LE                             '<='
  6    ASSIGN                         '='
  7    GT                             '>'
  8    ADD                            '+'
  9    SUB                            '-'
  10   MUL                            '*'
  11   DIV                            '/'
  12   EQ                             '=='
  13   ADD                            '+'
  14   SUB                            '-'
  15   MUL                            '*'
  16   DIV                            '/'
  17   IDENTIFIER                     'w'
  18   SEPARATOR                      '$'
  19   LBRACE                         '{'
  20   RBRACE                         '}'
  21   SEMICOLON                      ';'
  22   COMMA                          ','
  23   LPAREN                         '('
  24   RPAREN                         ')'
  25   ASSIGN                         '='
  26   RPAREN                         ')'
  27   LPAREN                         '('
  28   INTEGER                        'integer'
  29   BOOLEAN                        'boolean'
  30   REAL                           'real'
  31   LBRACE                         '{'
  32   RBRACE                         '}'
  33   SEMICOLON                      ';'
  34   COMMA                          ','
  35   IF                             'if'
  36   ELSE                           'else'
  37   IDENTIFIER                     'endif'
  38   RETURN                         'return'
  39   SCAN                           'scan'
  40   WHILE                          'while'
  41   ENDWHILE                       'endwhile'
  42   TRUE                           'true'
  43   FALSE                          'false'
  44   INTEGER_LITERAL                '1'
  45   INTEGER_LITERAL                '1000'
  46   INTEGER_LITERAL                '99'
  47   INTEGER_LITERAL                '00000000000000'
  48   REAL_LITERAL                   '234.567'
  49   REAL_LITERAL                   '9.000001'
  50   REAL_LITERAL                   '000.00'
  51   IDENTIFIER                     'z12_d_'
  52   IDENTIFIER                     'Zzzz'
  53   IDENTIFIER                     'a1z4r'
  54   IDENTIFIER                     'zbc12__x'
  55   IDENTIFIER                     'x'
  56   IGNORED_CHAR                   '#'
  57   IGNORED_CHAR                   '_'
  58   INTEGER_LITERAL                '23'
  59   IDENTIFIER                     'rty'
  60   INTEGER_LITERAL                '000'
  61   IGNORED_CHAR                   '.'
  62   IGNORED_CHAR                   '.'
  63   INTEGER_LITERAL                '123'

The error message you posted originates from a parser rule, which is correct: there is no parser rule that matches your entire example input.
